# Does face ID support for android in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, biometrics, face, unlock, face-id

i am trying to implement faceID for android in flutter. My android phone has face unlock feature but unable to detect while running my flutter app in phone. i am using below code :

```
Future<void> _getListOfBiometricTypes() async {
    List<BiometricType> listofBiometrics;
    try {
      listofBiometrics = await _localAuthentication.getAvailableBiometrics();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _availableBiometricTypes = listofBiometrics;
      print(_availableBiometricTypes.length);
      print(_availableBiometricTypes.toString());
    });
  }
```

only finger print detected. Why not showing face ID detection?